# Why no data found in jsp?

Tags: mysql, jsp

My JSP connects to MySQL database then I can print all data in result set But when I use `If()` I get an exception

> "No data found"

Here's my code

```
while (driverSet.next()) 
{
   if (driverSet.getString("EmpCode").equals(txtDriver)) 
   {
      out.println("<option value='" + driverSet.getString("EmpCode") + "' selected >" +      driverSet.getString("Name") + "</option>");
   } 
   else 
   {
      out.println("<option value='" + driverSet.getString("EmpCode") + "' >" + driverSet.getString("Name") + "</option>");
   }
}
```

Comment: You use JDBC in your JSP? Don't.

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace?

Comment: Learn MVC architecture.

Comment: What's driverSet? Is it a normal result set?

Comment: Consider to use `txtDriver.equals(driverSet.getString("EmpCode"))` it is much more safety in case of null-string